# Connecting from win7 to VirtualBox/CentOS/MySQL

Tags: virtualbox, centos, mysql

I am running VirtualBox 4.2.16 in Win7. There I have MySQL server in CentOS 6.4. Telnet from Win7 to CentOS is fine.

`mysql -u root -h 192.168.56.102 p` in CentOS is fine.

This is what I have in the user table:

```
mysql> select user, host from user;
+------+----------------+
| user | host           |
+------+----------------+
| mm   | 127.0.0.1      |
| root | 127.0.0.1      |
| mm   | 192.168.56.102 |
| root | 192.168.56.102 |
| mm   | localhost      |
| root | localhost      |
+------+----------------+

6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL status:

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.13, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      14
Current database:   
Current user:       root@loc
SSL:            Not in use
...
Connection:     192.168.56.102 via TCP/IP

/usr/my.cnf:

[mysqld]

log_bin
port = 3306
bind-address = 192.168.56.102

/etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.56.102 loc
```

Still, when I try to connect from Win7/HeidiSQL to root on 192.168.56.102 port 3306,
I get

> SQL Error (1130)... Host '192.168.56.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

CentOS firewall is down, but, as far as I understand, this is not a firewall isue...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try By giving  `Access` to the particular ip ,

The command would be like this :

```
# mysql -u root mysql

mysql> grant all on test.* to 'username'@'192.168.56.1';
```

You can refer adding user account of sql forums [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-users.html)

Comment: I already gave full access to root and mm. It did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I see you said centos firewall was down, but I found my problem was the centos firewall (firewalld) [blocking my requests].

Turning off the firewall proved it:

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

And adding a rule to allow the port to be open seemed to fix things:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```